# CKeditor ajax with codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, ckeditor

I had successfully installed CKeditor plugin on a textarea in Html view in a codeingiter project.

the problem that I use "ajax" form post and it seems that the content of CKeditor textarea does not sent with other fields.

I tried this solution to add

```
var VariableName = escape(FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKEditorFieldName').GetXHTML());
```

but "firebug" show me an error message that "**FCKeditorAPI is not defined**" then the page redirected to a white page contains json output message.

can you help me to send content of CKeditor textarea with ajax.

Comment: have you tried using `.GetData()`? also, on your CKEditor initialization use this setting `htmlEncodeOutput: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **CK** editor or **FCK** editor?

With the first (non-jquery version) you just need the **[.getData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)** function to get the data content of the field:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
var field = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

If you're using the jQUery Adapter I think it's enough doing:

```
var field = $( '#editor1' ).val();
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem that when I search about "CKEditor" the "FCKeditor" results are always displayed .

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too, don't know why..you need to go to ckeditor website directly and search for developer's documentation. It's a pretty nice resource indeed, too bad google ignores it